Topology Mendelson Lemma 5.6 Greatest lowest bound clarification
In Mendelson's book [Introduction to toplogy, 3rd edition] on page 50, Lemma 5.6 is stated as:

Let b be the greatest lower bound  of the non-empty set $\mathbf{A}$ of real numbers. Then, for each $\eta \gt 0, \exists x \in \mathbf{A}$ such that $x - b < \eta$

This is followed by a proof by contradiction that states that if this weren't true , then $b$ wouldn't the greatest lowest bound which makes sense
However looking at this again
$x < \eta + b$
My question: how is it that this can hold when there is a  difference (infinitely small difference) between Greatest lowest bound and $x$ (where $x$ is the minimal element of $A$) and my chosen most minimal $\eta$ i.e the next big thing after 0 , which is somehow expected  to overcome the previously stated difference and not just cover the difference ?
Is it possible that I have wandered into the murky waters of infinity?

'the next big thing after $0$' has no meaning.

@geetha290krm  is there a reason such doesn't have a meaning? In the same breathe, is it possible to prove this lemma without resorting to proof by contradiction?

What do you mean by "the next big thing after $0?$" I don't know what that is supposed to mean.
